# Unable to set JDK path in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, jdk, intellij

I am trying to get started with IntelliJ IDEA, however I am not able to set the JDK path. `which java` returns /usr/bin/java, however IDEA is not able to find the specified path. Expanding bin in the tree from within IDEA shows an unending tree of X11. I also tried /usr/share/java, but that gives an error 'specified path not a directory for JDK'
How do I set the JDK path?

Answer (score 8):

The error message is quite clear:

> specified path **not a directory** for JDK

`/usr/bin/java` it is not a directory to JDK is command for running compiled java programs `.class` files.

For setup JDK in IntelliJ go to [`Project Structure`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html#project_sdk) in section `Platform Settings` choose `SDKs` and add path to JDK usually on Ubuntu it installed in `/usr/lib/jvm/`. After that in section `Project Settings` choose `Project` tab and finally select added JDK:

[image]

Comment: usr/lib/jvm doesn't exist on my system

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya What way did you used for installing JDK ? And also say me what command `echo $JAVA_HOME` will print.

Comment: I installed java using webupd8 ppa. Also echo $JAVA_HOME doesn't return anything. The thing is IDEA doesn't work, however Android Studio which is based on IDEA works perfectly.

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya You have any configuration in `SDKs` (as on screenshot) section in Android Studio ? If so add the same configurations in IntelliJ.

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya It's very strange that you said about `/usr/lib/jvm` doesn't exist on your system. As I see by this **[guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)** your JDK should be located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` folder

Comment: You need to download an oracle jdk - unpack tar.gz and point Project SDK to unpacked dir

Comment: does it make a difference in using a JDK present in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` Or  `/opt/java/jdk-10.0.2` folder?. Also,I found `JAVA_HOME` path in my `/etc/environment file`: `JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk-10.0.2/bin" ` and When, I followed the above post sugegstions to set the JAVA_HOME path: `JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::") ` and did `echo $JAVA_HOME` what I get was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/` In what ways these two `JAVA_HOME` path are different,what I did wrong?any suggestion on how to fix it.Also,I have no permission to edit `/etc/environment`

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and fresh IDEA 2019.2.

I have met the same problem and solved it by installing several openjdk packages.
"openjdk-8-jdk" alone is not enough.

For OpenJDK 8 (1.8) you need to install:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-demo openjdk-8-doc openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-source
```

For OpenJDK 11:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-demo openjdk-11-doc openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-source
```

Then both SDKs are recognized correctly (choose one of subfolders in /usr/lib/jvm/ folder).

Comment: Since Oracle JDK is no longer free to use like it used to, not to mention old answers are already old, this answer is very helpful now.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As Kirill Mikhailov pointed out, using oracle jdk instead of the already installed open jdk has solved the issue for me 
I'm using Intelij 2017.2 CE

Comment: Issue was with Linux not finding the correct folder due to some reason, I had Oracle JDK. Also, IntelliJ works equally well with Open JDK. This issue has been resolved long back :)

Comment: Yes switching to oracle-java-8 solved my issue too.